# Python does not find installed modules

Tags: python, virtualenv

Python3.5 does not locate installed modules when invoked in virtual env.

1. Create virtual env: `python3.5 -m venv autogit/venv && cd autogit`
2. `source venv/bin/activate`
3. `which python` == `...autogit/venv/bin/python`
   Weird, would expect python3.5
4. Add my python source code to `/autogit` and `pip freeze>requirements.txt`
5. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
6. `ls venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages` shows `request-0-0-0-py3.5.egg-info` and some other stuff
7. Since dependencies are installed under python3.5 and `which python` revealed python rather than `python3.5`, lets invoke the python3.5binary explicitly.... `venv/bin/python3.5 autogit.py`
   Get `ImportError: No module named 'request`

???  Where could python be looking for packages if not in my virtual env?

**UPDATE** The questions above remain unanswered; here are things I noticed since then and the workaround I used:

- `pip install` produced a file `request-0-0-0-py3.5.egg-info`. It did NOT produce an actual `request` directory with the source code or binaries for this module.  Also why is it version 0 0 0 that is fishy
- After some googling I noticed the module I wanted seemed to be named `requests` not `request` which is what was in my source. I changed it requests, `pip install`, and everything works. It was hard to see that there was a mistake because `pip install`ing `request` did not fail

Comment: Start python, `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: I did exactly what you did, found "requests"  in venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages, so maybe some OS setup-missed up or sth

Comment: @kindall `['', '/Users/xxx/Documents/ab/dev/autogit/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload']`

Comment: There you go, that's where Python is looking for packagaes.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense though. As stated in the original question, `ls/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages` (the second entry above) reveals  `request-0-0-0-py3.5.egg-info `, so all good, right?  Somehow no: running `python` or `venv/bin/python3.5` produces the importError

Answer (score 1):

Have you got other Python versions installed? That might be the problem.

Try using `pip3` instead of `pip`

Comment: There are other versions of python installed, but I dont see why this should matter since I explicitly invoked the python3.5 binary, no?  Also, seeing as `site-packages` was found under `python3.5` is it not safe to assume that `pip3` was used?

Comment: Nonetheless, did as you suggested: `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` unexpectedly produces `You must give at least one requirement to install`